# Return to previous position after catch statement

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a piece of code that has a loop within a try statement. When an exception is thrown and caught, the loop is broken out of, and the execution continues along its way.. How could I get the execution to continue through the rest of the loop after the catch block is finished?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
private ArrayList<URL> download(final InputStream in, URL url, int maxDepth) throws IOException {
  try {
    ...
    for (final URL link : links) {
      //if exception is caught, loop will be broken here.........
      download(link.openStream(), link, maxDepth - 1);
    }
    return alLinks;

  } catch (final IOException e) {
    // Display an error if anything fails.
    this.searchResults.append(e.getMessage());
    return null;
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's any simple-minded way to slip back into right before the for loop ends, so that it can finish iterating through the rest of the elements..

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the `try-catch` block into the for loop.

```
private ArrayList<URL> download(final InputStream in, URL url, int maxDepth) throws IOException {
    ...
    for (final URL link : links) {
      //if exception is caught, loop will be broken here.........
      try{
        download(link.openStream(), link, maxDepth - 1);
      }
      catch (final IOException e) {
    // Display an error if anything fails.
    this.searchResults.append(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
    return alLinks;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course.. how simple! I just have to rearrange some stuff.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `try` block within the loop:

```
for (...) {
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this has implications for runtime or anything like that, but as long as the cases in which the exception is actually thrown are rare (a.k.a. "exceptional" :-P) I wouldn't expect it to make a significant difference.

Comment: In general, it could make a significant difference, performance-wise.  But there's not much you can do about that, unless you can avoid the exception being thrown in the first place.  (In this case, the cost of creating/throwing/catching an exception is likely to be small relative to the cost of attempting to connect to a remote server.)